# Return MySQL rows from .exec(err,rows) to a function in Sails JS(i dont want to send rows in response)

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sails.js

How can i return the rows of a table (model) if i don't want to send it to response via `response.json()` of `response.ok()`.

i have `user` model
api/model/User.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string'
    },
    age:{
      type:'text'
    }
  }
};
```

I am writing a function in api/services/sendList.js

```
module.exports=function sendList(model){
  model.find({}).exec(function(err,rows){
   //here i dont want to send it as res.json(rows)
  });
   /***i want to return the rows obtained so that it can be used
    *somewhere else(wherever the function **sendList** is being
    *called.)
    */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback, or promises.  Here is a callback example :

```
module.exports=function sendList(model,callback){
  model.find({}).exec(function(err,rows){
    callback(rows);
  });
}
```

To use it :

```
sendlList(model, function(rows) {
    console.log(rows);

    // Go ahead and use them now.
});
```

Comment: callback is a good way to perform the task i want.But Is there a way exissting where i can return the array of row objects.

Comment: So due to async feature of node the only way possible is callback!!

Answer (score 0):

Gary's response works.

Or just `return`:

```
module.exports.sendList = function(model){
  model.find().exec(function(err,rows){
    if(!err) return rows;
  });
}
```

Comment: That will not work...  sendList will return before results are available.

Comment: console.log(getList(User));
and this was printing undefined

Comment: If you don't know why this does not work, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323